# Delphi syntax for a table indexed on two or more fields

Tags: delphi, syntax, dbase

I have a Table indexed on field1 and on field2.

How do I specify, in the TTable component, that both indexes are active.

I tried:

```
IndexFieldNames := 'FIELD1, FIELD2';
```

It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a dBASE table.

dBASE tables must have a multi-field index created explicitly.

I created a new index on 'FIELD1+FIELD2' called MyIndex.

Then I set:

```
IndexName := 'MyIndex';
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexFieldNames := 'FIELD1;FIELD2';

Comment: It says "No index for field names: FIELD1;FIELD2"